# Express session cookie not being set in browser

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, amazon-elb

I'm facing an issue trying to implement HTTPS via a proxy (initially NGINX, now AWS ALB) to secure connections to my node server. My `login` request is being processed just fine, but subsequent requests after `login` are being marked as `isAuthenticated === false`, and therefore my node app is returning 401.

I know `isAuthenticated === false` is being caused by the session cookie not being set in the browser, however I can't seem to figure out why the session cookie isn't being set (or sent?).

I'm configuring express-session as below:

```
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));

app.set('trust proxy', 1);

// add & configure middleware
app.use(session({
    name: 'session',
    store: new redisStore(),
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { httpOnly: true,
        secure: true }
}));
```

My node app is sitting behind an AWS Application Load Balancer which communicates with the app over HTTP, so I've configured `trust proxy` to 1.

My passport configuration and local strategy are just below that:

```
// configure passport.js to use the local strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    { usernameField: 'email' }, 
    (email, password, done) => {
        mysql.getConnection((err, conn) => {
            conn.query('SELECT u.user_id, u.email, u.password, o.uuid FROM user AS u INNER JOIN organization AS o ON o.id = u.org_id WHERE email = ?;', [email], ( err, rows ) => {
                if (err) throw err;

                if (rows.length !== 1)
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'User does not exist.\n' });
                else if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password))
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.\n' });
                else{
                    return done(null, {user_id: rows[0].user_id, email: email, uuid: rows[0].uuid});
                }
            });
            conn.release();
        });
    }
));
```

The request coming from the react client is:

```
axios.post('https://sub.mydomain.com' + '/api/login', userObj, {withCredentials: true})
.then(res => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
        initUser(res.data, true);
    }
    else {
        this.setState({errors: {password: 'Incorrect username or password'}})

        this.props.history.push('/login');
    }
})
.catch((e) => {
    this.setState({errors: {password: 'Unable to login'}})

    this.props.history.push('/login');
});
```

When making the request I'm getting returned a 200 status with the user information as I would expect. See the screenshots from PostMan below:
[image]

Also these are the response headers in Chrome:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://sub.mydomain.com
content-length: 89
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 12 Mar 2019 07:49:45 GMT
etag: W/"59-T0xi+VpB6A/MLCHMb8Qz3Pq9dwc"
status: 200
vary: Origin
x-powered-by: Express
```

Somewhere along the line it seems the session cookie is either failing to be sent from the node app, or set in the browser.

I'm running the exact same on my local machine and the cookie is being set in the browser no problem. The only difference between my local and my server is the ALB in front of the node application, and I'm setting `secure: false` on my local (as I'm not using HTTPS).

FYI - I had initially tried using an NGINX proxy_pass on my server to handle the HTTPS connections and had the same issue. I had tried removing the proxy pass and using the AWS Application Load Balancer after failing to find a solution with NGINX (I thought there may be an issue with my NGINX config). This leads me to believe the issue is with the express-session configuration as its the common denominator here, however I may be missing something else.

FYI 2 - I've tried setting `trust proxy` to `true`, `1`, `2`, `3`, etc, Also tried setting `secure` to `false`, Also tried setting `httpOnly` to `false` - and countless variations of the above, but still I don't seem to be getting the cookie in the browser.

FYI 3 - I tried removing the proxy and reverting back to a direct HTTP connection to the Node application and I'm still not getting the cookie on in my browser (or in PostMan).

Hoping someone here can point out something I've missed in the hopes of getting this resolved.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after days of investigating, the issue turned out to be that my Redis server had terminated and failed to restart.  *facepalm*

The sessionID wasn't being generated (or stored) as it couldn't connect to the Redis store to save the session information on the server side.

Starting the Redis server solved the issue immediately, however it would be great if express/passport had some verbose logging to notify users of this.

Hope someone else finds this useful!